# How can you get the value of an ENUM within a MySQL Procedure

Tags: mysql, enums, procedures

It seems to me that enums are broken within MySQL, at least on version 5.0.51a-24+lenny5 (Debian).  I have a simple lookup table which contains an enum field:

```
CREATE TABLE `FrameworkServices` (
  ...
  `DNSType` enum('IP','CNAME') NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

Ad-hoc, I can run the following without issue:

```
SELECT DNSType, CNameOrIP INTO @hackEnum, @ipAddress
FROM FrameworkServices WHERE FrameworkTypeId = 1 LIMIT 1;
SELECT @hackEnum, @ipAddress;
```

However, if I put the EXACT same code into a Procedure, @hackEnum returns empty (not null, at least through TOAD).

I have tried selecting DNSType+0, CONCAT(DNSType,'') and everything else that seems to be valid on enums and the result is the same:
   EVERY article I read works ad-hoc, but returns empty within the Procedure!

I've even tried using local variables and defining hackEnum as the same ENUM type.

Comment: NOTE: I don't like this enum, but I have to live with it for now (inherited code), so please don't suggest retyping the enum to use a lookup table, even though this is ultimately the best answer.

Comment: Vague possibility: try `@hackEnum := DNSType, @ipAddress := CNameOrIp` instead, in case it's some weird parser bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem - I was retrieving an ENUM value and then checking it via `IF...ELSE...END IF`.  It wasn't working and driving me nuts as to why not.  The solution was to select into a char(1) and then treat the ENUM column value as a string:

```
DECLARE use_free CHAR(1);

SELECT use_free INTO use_free FROM ...;

IF use_free = '1' THEN
  <do something>
ELSE
  <do something else>
END IF;
```

I first used:

```
DECLARE use_free ENUM('0','1');
```

and while technically correct, failed.  Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Only declare your variable of return, has varchar(xx);

```
CREATE TABLE `FrameworkServices` (
  ...
  `DNSType` enum('IP','CNAME') NOT NULL,
  ...
)

declare valor varchar(40);
select DNSType from FrameworkServices into valor;
```

and this all!!